# Need recommendations for free ERD software

Tags: erd

Need to build some ERD's, what good/lightweight/free software would you recommend that can make building ERD's easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for sure. Multiple styles to choose from, very flexible, and multiple output formats. It's also free and open source.

See my post on it in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/67574/tool-for-dependency-graphs/67578#67578) as well.

Comment: thanks, looking at your sample code sure made it a lot easier to grasp